# New added UITabelView cell is hidden when keyboard is showing in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Currently I designed to add new line cell in UITableView when user press return button of keyboard. But problem is after 4 or 5 uitableview cell are added, new cell are hidden under keyboard. I'm trying to solve to adjust uitableview when return key is pressed but failed.

Following is my code.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        CoachPadItem *newCoachPadItem = [[CoachPadItem alloc]init];
        newCoachPadItem.coachpadDescription = @"NULL";
        newCoachPadItem.coachpadTagId = @"0";
        [_tagPointsArray addObject:newCoachPadItem];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_tagPointsArray count]-1 inSection:0];
        [_coachpadTableView beginUpdates];

        CoachPadPointCell *cell = (CoachPadPointCell*)[_coachpadTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0];
        [cell.txtPoint becomeFirstResponder];

        isType = TRUE;
        if ([isDelete isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            isDelete = @"2";
        }

        [_coachpadTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [_coachpadTableView endUpdates];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 4-5 cell added, do this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = - 170;
self.view.frame = frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

after your typing is finshed, set y again to 0